# Windows bundle install: HOME environment variable (or HOMEDRIVE and HOMEPATH) must be set and point to a directory (RuntimeError)

Tags: windows, rubygems, bundler

I installed bundler succesfully with

```
gem install bundler
```

Then I try to do

```
bundle install
```

I get following error:

```
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rbreadline.rb:1097:in `<module:RbReadline>': HOME environment variable (or HOMEDRIVE and HOMEPATH) must be set and point to a directory (RuntimeError)
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rbreadline.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/readline.rb:10:in `<module:Readline>'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/readline.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/line_editor/readline.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/line_editor.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/vendored_thor.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/exe/bundle:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/bin/bundle:22:in `load'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/bin/bundle:22:in `<main>'
```

Seems to be error with environment variables, however those are set properly in my system

```
set HOME
HOMEDRIVE=C:
HOMEPATH=\Users\My Näme
```

Yes, I have scandinavian letter in my name so I'm wondering if that is the problem. I've faced that once before with web2py installer I think.

Anyway, any ideas how to solve that problem?

Answer (score 23):

You are likely to face this problem if you are on a domain PC and your PC is setup as part of an active directory. In this case your `HOMEPATH`, `HOMEDRIVE` and `HOME` environment variables are set in your enterprise active directory or domain. Once out of the domain group or when disconnected from company network you loose access to these variables hence the error. Use `setx`in windows for permanent environment variables to override enterprise ones and restart your system for it to take effect.

```
SETX HOMEDRIVE %SYSTEMDRIVE% -m
SETX HOMEPATH \Users\%username% -m
SET HOME=%SYSTEMDRIVE%\Users\%USERNAME%
SETX HOME "%HOME%"
SET TEMP=%HOME%\Local Settings\Temp
SETX TEMP "%TEMP%"
SETX TMP "%TEMP%"
```

This is tested on windows 10 and it works. Either copy and paste it in a script and drop in your startup folder or paste it line by line in `CMD` or `PowerShell`. Alternatively set is as task using `Task Scheduler`.
**Note** When using `setx` wrap strings with spaces in them with double quotes.

Comment: I tried this but no effect. Still same error message is shown after "bundle install"

Comment: Are you on a domain PC? Try running `echo %HOMEPATH%`, `echo %HOMEDRIVE%`. Make sure what's printed in your console window is resolved to a local drive and path. Restarting your computer after applying the changes I suggested is important. It may not work on Windows XP and Vista

Comment: worked in Windows 7 also, no full restart required - just restarted the cmd shell

Comment: Doesn't work for me either, using Win 10 enterprise on my work laptop.

Answer (score 1):

Run `Get-ChildItem Env:` it will return all your env variables.  Check to make sure HOME and HOMEPATH are correct.

`HOME -> C:\Users\Eric`
`HOMEPATH -> \Users\Eric`

You can use commands below to fix: 
`Remove-Variable -Force HOME`
`Set-Variable HOME "C:\Users\(enter your username)"`

Answer (score 0):

I get the same error when i was excuting "bundle exec jekyll s" Which is so weird that I have never got the error before. Then I tried to reinsall the bundle with "gem install bundler". Then another wanring showed:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied @ rb_file_s_stat - C:/WINDOWS/system32/config/systemprofile
```

It gives me a clue. I just navigate to the directory and give the permission it needs. Then the problem is solved.
What a beautiful day it is!